# How to get processid and processname for a specific port

Tags: linux, shell

I want to write a shell-script such that it should ask for a port number then show the process-id and process-name running on that port number. So how can I do this in Linux?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lsof` to do so, with the `-i` option to filter the port you want. The first column is the command name and the second one is its pid.

```
lsof -i :$port | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1" "$2 }'
```

I'm using `tail` to remove the header from the output of `lsof`. Note that there is a simpler solution to get the pid alone, using the `-t` option:

```
lsof -t -i :$port
```